# Como rodar um modelo para cada subset de dados de uma serie temporal por ver

Tags: r

Eu tenho uma base de dados que tem informação de consumo de ração de animais (190 animais) a cada dia (88 dias).
Segue abaixo

```
table1 <- read.csv("Data.csv", header = TRUE) 
table1
```

```html
Animal Dia Consumo
1 1 245
1 2 256
1 3 300
1 4 450
2 1 245
2 2 256
2 3 300
2 4 450
```

```
x = table1$Dia

y = table1$Consumo

Animal=table1$Animal
```

## Primeiro eu preciso rodar um modelo DLM (já tenho o programa) somente para um animal.

```
runDLM = function(beta) { x, y,........ }
```

## Depois eu preciso rodar para todos os animais. Para todos os animais eu pensei no comando descrito abaixo, mas não sei se esta certo

```
for (Animal in 1:190) {
    runDLM(beta)
    }
```

Comment: Parece estar errado, a função `runDLM` não depende de `Animal`, não é um argumento da função, o único argumento é `beta`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, como geralmente se fala em tutoriais de R, "se tá usando um for-loop, ta fazendo errado". Além deixar o código um pouco mais lento, vc não está utilizando um dos fatores mais importantes da linguagem, que é a sua orientação funcional, extremamente útil em problemas como o seu: aplicar funções complexas estruturadamente em dados.

A resposta do Robert está corretíssima. Ofereci apenas uma versão mais moderna utilizando os pacotes `dplyr + tidyr`, `broom` e `purrr` para:

1. gerar dados com a mesma estrutura que nos mostrou
2. estimar um modelo linear simples nos dados gerados
3. extrair os coeficientes estimados de cada modelo

A estrutura do meu código deve lhe ajudar à estimar os seus modelos sem problemas.

```
library(tidyverse)

## gerando dados com a mesma estrutura apresentada

set.seed(134)

df <- 
  tibble(Animal = 1:190, taxa = runif(n = 190, min = 3, max = 23)) %>%  
  crossing(dia = 0:3) %>%
  mutate(consumo = 245 + dia*taxa)


df


# A tibble: 760 x 4
   Animal    taxa   dia  consumo
   <int>     <dbl> <int>    <dbl>
1      1  7.007272     0 245.0000
2      1  7.007272     1 252.0073
3      1  7.007272     2 259.0145
4      1  7.007272     3 266.0218
5      2 15.551850     0 245.0000
6      2 15.551850     1 260.5518
7      2 15.551850     2 276.1037
8      2 15.551850     3 291.6555
9      3 20.629976     0 245.0000
10     3 20.629976     1 265.6300
# ... with 750 more rows
```

Agora vamos estimar um modelo linear simples com `lm` para a função `consumo ~ dia` e extrair os coeficientes de cada modelo com o auxílio da função `broom::tidy`, que extrai os coeficientes e estatísticas em um `data.frame` "tidy"(limpo):

```
## gerando um modelo linear no dia para cada animal e extraindo os coeficientes  --------------

df %>% 
  group_by(Animal) %>% 
  nest(.key = dados_animal) %>% 
  mutate(model = map(dados_animal, ~lm(consumo ~ dia, data = .))) %>% 
  mutate(coef = map(model, broom::tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(coef)
```

Resultando em:

```
# A tibble: 380 x 6
   Animal        term   estimate    std.error    statistic      p.value
   <int>       <chr>      <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
1      1 (Intercept) 245.000000 1.174950e-15 2.085196e+17 2.299886e-35
2      1         dia   7.007272 6.280370e-16 1.115742e+16 8.032903e-33
3      2 (Intercept) 245.000000 0.000000e+00          Inf 0.000000e+00
4      2         dia  15.551850 0.000000e+00          Inf 0.000000e+00
5      3 (Intercept) 245.000000 4.699798e-15 5.212990e+16 3.679818e-34
6      3         dia  20.629976 2.512148e-15 8.212086e+15 1.482836e-32
7      4 (Intercept) 245.000000 0.000000e+00          Inf 0.000000e+00
8      4         dia   8.025121 0.000000e+00          Inf 0.000000e+00
9      5 (Intercept) 245.000000 0.000000e+00          Inf 0.000000e+00
10     5         dia  15.198999 0.000000e+00          Inf 0.000000e+00
# ... with 370 more rows
```

Para aprender mais sobre o jeito "tidyverse" de se programar, recomendo dar uma olhada nos artigos no [site](https://www.tidyverse.org/) do pacute e no livro [R for Data Sceince](http://r4ds.had.co.nz), principalmente na parte sobre como trabalhar com [muitos modelos](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html), pois é basicamente como apresentei essa resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Inventei dados e uma função, mas pode usar a mesma lógica:

```
set.seed(123)
table1 = data.frame(Animal=rep(1:6,each=10),Dia=rep(1:4,15), Consumo=round(runif(60,240,500),0))

runDLM = function(beta,dat) { 
  x=dat$Dia 
  y=dat$Consumo
  coef(lm(y~I(x^beta)))
  }

sdat=split(table1,table1$Animal)
betat=2
sapply(sdat,runDLM,beta=betat)


#                         1          2          3          4          5          6
#    (Intercept) 355.804959 319.156589 376.897521 398.223256 313.494215 369.547287
#    I(x^beta)     5.322314   6.699225   3.538843  -2.167442   2.523967  -1.993798
```